# Avoid re-calling API - MongoDB from google cloud function

Tags: java, mongodb, google-cloud-functions

I'm using MongoDB to save JSON outputs from a cloud function. I'd like for it to automatically output previously searched terms. For example, in pic attached, the two JSON outputs are of the same search result, but occupy different ObjectId. The cloud function calls the API that delivers the JSON when it is already stored, and I'd like for it to output the search result already generated previously. How can I do this? [JSON output from same search result - example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obkEq.png)

I tried writing an iterative program to prevent this, but it didn't account for all results.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent duplicates from going into the database (unique index), collapse to have distinct results when coming out ($group), or something else?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to prevent duplicates.